# Passing error messages from one controller to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a contact form on my site. It works fine, here's the code:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new(:id => 1)
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    if @contact.save
      redirect_to('/', :notice => "Message sent ....")
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Oops, something went wrong. Please try again"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end

#contact
  = simple_form_for @contact, :url=>{:controller=>:contacts, :action=>:create}, :html=>{:method=>:post} do |f|
    = render 'shared/error_messages', :target => @contact
    = f.input  :name
    = f.input  :email
    = f.input  :subject
    = f.input  :body, :as => :text, :input_html => { :rows => 5 }
    = f.submit "Send"
```

I've decided that I want to embed the contact form in my homepage at `pages/index.html.haml`

So I stuck the form in a partial, link to it at the bottom of my homepage and add an instance variable to the index action in my pages controller. If I fill out the form correctly, the email gets sent and everything is great.

But if form submission fails, the :new action from the contacts_controller is rendered when really I'd prefer the :index action of the pages_controller. I know I can redirect to this action using `redirect_to "/"` but I don't get the error_messages on the form when I do it this way.

How can I transfer control from contacts_controller to pages_controller and include the error messages on the failed form submission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you will branch your code when there is a failure to create in the create action to the correct page but if you want to redirect, then you dont want flash.now.

Basically

```
if @contact.save
  redirect_to('/', :notice => "Message sent ....")
else
  if (should new page be shown check)
    flash.now[:error] = "Oops, something went wrong. Please try again"
    render 'new'
  else
    flash[:error] = "Oops ... "
    redirect_to somelocation_path
  end
end
```